# How to upgrade php 5.2.10 to 5.2.11 using YUM on centOS

Tags: php, centos, yum

I can't find the commands anywhere.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you don't have the software in your existing repositories, a great source is the "Remi" repository

To import the repository

```
su -
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi.repo
```

The repository is disabled by default so when you want to use install something you will need to type the following (for example)

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install mysql
```

You will also need the EPEL repository on which this one depends (just use the same syntax to get it) full documentaton on EPEL is here: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

If you need to import the key (normally not necessary when you use yum, but I've known keys not to download)

```
rpm --import RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
`yum update php`
```

Your repositories will have to have 5.2.11, though.

Comment: that is what I am missing... do you know where to get that repository?